# How to get the destination ListView item on drop?

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

In UWP C#, I have one ListView in upper row & another in lower row. When I drag a listitem from upper ListView & drop it on lower ListView, I am getting the source. But, I am unable to get the destination. ie) the listview item/(Folder object in my case) where I dropped.

```
<ListView Name="ListviewCars" 
            CanDragItems="True" DragItemsStarting="ListviewCars_DragItemsStarting"     
            SelectionMode="Single" IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            DataContext="Cars"  ItemsSource="{Binding CarsCollection}">

            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel  Background="Transparent"  Height="80" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Name="GrdCars" >
                        <Grid Height="80" Width="90" Padding="5">
                            <Grid.Background>
                                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Assets/car.png"/>
                            </Grid.Background>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>                        
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>



        <ListView Name="GrdViewImg"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            AllowDrop="True" DragOver="Image_DragOver" 
            Drop="Image_OnDrop"
            DataContext="Folders"  ItemsSource="{Binding FolderCollection}">

            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="Transparent"  Height="80" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Name="GrdForFolderMenu" RightTapped="GrdForFolderMenu_RightTapped">
                        <Grid Height="80" Width="90" Padding="5">
                            <Grid.Background>
                                <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="Assets/Folderimage.png"/>
                            </Grid.Background>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>                       
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Is it WPF or UWP? It cannot be both. Please correct the tags so that some one can help you better.

Comment: Sorry. It is UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a simple solution myself. I get the source from DragItemsStarting event of the SoureListView. and target item (as mentioned by ashchuk) from a Grid placed inside Datatemplate of Target ListView. as shown below. Everything works fine now! 
(Cars is my Source custom list item. Folders is my Target custom list item)

```
    private void SoureListView_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        Cars x = e.Items[0] as Cars;
        string DraggedSourceCar = x.Name;
        e.Data.Properties.Add("myArgs", DraggedSourceCar);
    }

    private void GridInsideDatatemplateOfTargetListview_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = sender as Grid;
        var y = x.DataContext as Folders;
        string toMoveFolderName = y.Name;

        string DraggedSourceCar = e.DataView.Properties["myArgs"].ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(DraggedSourceCar + Environment.NewLine + toMoveFolderName );
    }

    private void TargetListview_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop) sample?
After some research I found what `DragEventArgs` contains an `OriginalSource` property with `Name` matches the name of target list when `Drop` event invoked.

I'm not checked it with folders and subfolders, but maybe `OriginalSource` will contain folder where item dropped.

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="8,4"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Text="All Items"/>

    <ListView x:Name="SourceListView"
        Grid.Row="2" Margin="8,4"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        CanDragItems="True"
        DragItemsStarting="SourceListView_DragItemsStarting"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,4"
       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
       Text="Selection"/>

    <ListView x:Name="TargetListView"
       Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,4"
       AllowDrop="True" CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True"
       DragOver="TargetListView_DragOver"
       Drop="TargetListView_Drop"
       DragItemsStarting="TargetListView_DragItemsStarting"
       DragItemsCompleted="TargetListView_DragItemsCompleted"/>
```

And here is printscreen with fired breakpoint:

[image]

**EDIT:**

To get an item inside of TargetList you can do a trick.

I think you use `DataTemplate` to display custom list items ("folders"). You can see a sample below. As you see I add `Grid_DragOver` trigger.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="20,5" DragOver="Grid_DragOver" 
              BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5" AllowDrop="True">
            <TextBlock Margin="10" LineHeight="40" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

This way `Grid_DragOver` will be invoked when mouse pointer enter inside the `Grid` in `DataTemplate`. 
And if you use binding `List<YourFolderClass>` as data source, you'll get folder in `DataContext`. For example I used this:

```
var SampleData = new ObservableCollection<string>
            {
                "My Research Paper",
                "Electricity Bill",
                "My To-do list",
                "TV sales receipt",
                "Water Bill",
                "Grocery List",
                "Superbowl schedule",
                "World Cup E-ticket"
            };
```

[image]

You can see all code in [gist](https://gist.github.com/ashchuk/6ef279b5095fb32014ff14576d4648ae).

Comment: Hi sir, Thanks for your answer. As shown in your image, I am able to successfully get the dropped/source object, but not the designation object where I dropped!!  Also, The OriginalSource does not contain the designation ListView listitem, where I dropped!

Comment: Using, ListView lst = e.OriginalSource as ListView;, I can get designation  ListView. But how to get designation ListItem in it?
I tried in this way too:
var a = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as Folders;
But it returns null.

Comment: And folder where are you dropped down do not seems to be '''SelectedItem''' of target ListView?

Comment: No.It is not the SelectedItem!

Comment: See an **Edit** block in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out by yourself = DragEventArgs.GetPosition() in the destination drop, then the underlying item with smoe helper functions

```
public static object GetObjectAtPoint<ItemContainer>(this ItemsControl control, Point p)
                                     where ItemContainer : DependencyObject
        {
            // ItemContainer - can be ListViewItem, or TreeViewItem and so on(depends on control) 
            ItemContainer obj = GetContainerAtPoint<ItemContainer>(control, p);
            if (obj == null)
                return null;

            return control.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(obj);
        }

        public static ItemContainer GetContainerAtPoint<ItemContainer>(this ItemsControl control, Point p)
                                 where ItemContainer : DependencyObject
        {
            HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(control, p);
            if (result != null)
            {
                DependencyObject obj = result.VisualHit;

                while (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj) != null && !(obj is ItemContainer))
                {
                    obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
                }

                // Will return null if not found 
                return obj as ItemContainer;
            }
            else return null;
        }
```

Comment: Hi buddy, Hearty thanks for you answer. I got the, var point = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender) successfully. But in the GetContainerAtPoint class, it says, HitTestResult namespace does not exists in uwp. Also, VisualTreeHelper does not contain definition for HitTest.

Comment: this must help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625268/how-can-i-detect-the-control-under-a-point-in-uwp